# flash media server 2126 NetConnection object must be connected

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm use flash media server5 on flash CS6 try to play video but it never works. It always say:

```
{ArgumentError: Error #2126: NetConnection object must be connected
at flash.net::NetStream/ctor()
at flash.net::NetStream()
at flashmediaservertest_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()}
```

My code:

```
var my_nc:NetConnection =new NetConnection();
my_nc.connect("rtmp://127.0.0.1/flv/");
my_nc.client = this;
var my_ns= new NetStream(my_nc);
video.attachNetStream(my_ns);
my_ns.play("simple.flv");
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Do you actually have an instance of Flash Media Server running on your local PC?

Comment: Yes my Flash Media Server is running , and I can see my administration console is connecting

Comment: Then you should wait for the **NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS** event from the **my_nc** object which is dispatched upon successful connection (as described here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html#connect()) and only then attach it as the source of **my_ns** object.

Comment: Sorry,I am a little busy these days, but I will find time to try

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `connect` method of `NetConnection` is asynchronous.  This means that rather than freeze your whole program waiting for a response (which can sometimes take a while), the application moves on immediately to the rest of your code and dispatches an event when that connection is complete.

What you need to do, is add an event listener to your net connection so your program knows when that connection is complete. Then only after you know that connection is established run your net stream code.

Here is an example:

```
//instantiate your net connection (no change here)
var my_nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

//listen for the NET_STATUS event which you tell you when you have successfully connected or if your connection is lost etc.
my_nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, statusHandler);
my_nc.client = this;

my_nc.connect("rtmp://127.0.0.1/flv/");


function statusHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void {
    switch (e.info.code) {
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
            startStream();
            break;

        case "NetConnection.Connect.Closed":
            //your connection was closed
            break;
    }
}

function startStream():void {
    var my_ns= new NetStream(my_nc);
    video.attachNetStream(my_ns);
    my_ns.play("simple.flv");
}
```

You can see a list of all the different NET_STATUS info codes [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html).  It's a good idea to handle all the various connection errors too.